# HQL Inner Join across different packages

Tags: hibernate, hql, inner-join

```
<hibernate-mapping package="entity.associative">
  <class name="UserGroup" table="user_group">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
    This class contains user group information. 
    </meta>
    <composite-id>
      <key-property name="userID" column="u_id"/>
      <key-property name="groupID" column="g_id"/>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="hours" type="double">
      <column name="hours"/>
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping package="entity.user">
  <class name="User" table="user">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class contains user information. 
    </meta>
    <id name="userID" type="string">
        <column name="u_id" length="50"/>
    </id>

    <property name="fName" type="string">
        <column name="f_name" length="100"/>
    </property>
.
.
.
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I'm getting the error

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: 
Path expected for join! 
[FROM entity.user.User u INNER JOIN UserGroup ug 
    where u.userID = ug.userID and ug.groupID = 'EORG']
```

Most likely because they are in different packages - one in `entity.user`, another in `entity.associative`. Is there a way to change my query?

My current query is:

```
tx = session.beginTransaction();
String queryStr = "FROM User u INNER JOIN UserGroup ug where u.userID = ug.userID and ug.groupID = 'EORG'";
Query query = session.createQuery(queryStr);
userList = (ArrayList<User>) query.list();
```

Comment: Please, check my answer

Comment: Because you are newbie. If an answer accomplishes your question, please accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you must explicit package like this:

```
tx = session.beginTransaction();
String queryStr = "FROM entity.user.User u, 
    entity.associative.UserGroup ug 
    where u.userID = ug.userID and ug.groupID = 'EORG'";
Query query = session.createQuery(queryStr);
userList = (ArrayList) query.list();
```

Usually to prevent this behaviour I write my query like this:

```
String myQuery = " FROM " + User.class.getName() + " u, " + 
    UserGroup.class.getName() + " ug 
    where u.userID = ug.userID and ug.groupID = 'EORG'";
```

using getName() you have the complete path of your class

Comment: I don't think it is the reason.

Comment: @v.ladynev: Yes, the other reason can be in the mapping but in the associative class there is not an object User but only the userID property

Comment: I received a new error after trying to explicit the package. 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: DOT node with no left-hand-side!

Comment: try again without INNER JOIN but usgin comma (because not explicited the ON clause)

Comment: ah that worked! thank you so much. I prefer the new method that you suggested as I've used it for sql. Sorry for asking a bad question!

Comment: @klutznic It is a bad method. You will have a cartesian product. It is not an inner join, it is a cross join with a condition :)

Answer (score 0):

To join `User` and `UserGroup` you need to have an association in `User` to `UserGroup`

```
class User {

  @OneToOne
  private UserGroup userGroup;

}
```

`FROM User u INNER JOIN u.userGroup ug where ug.groupID = 'EORG'`

This query is just an example. It can be rewritten in a more simply form

`FROM User u where u.userGroup.groupID = 'EORG'`

Last version of Hibernate has ability to use joins without such associations, but it is need to use `on` clause.

Comment: You can join two entities using only the simple property (without onetoone or manytoone property)

Comment: @JoeTaras With last Hibernate versions and with `on` as in my edit. Anyway it is a bad practice.

Comment: From Hibernate 3 surely, before I don't remember. Why is a bad practice?

Comment: @JoeTaras Do you mean cross join (`User, UserGroup`) or `inner join on`?

Comment: The where clause tells INNER JOIN. When I write a SQL query comma for me is forbidden, in HQL explicit INNER JOIN are few. For example your solution can be write: FROM User WHERE u.userGroup.groupID = 'EORG' because if I map a oneToOne the JOIN is implicit.

Comment: `FROM User WHERE u.userGroup.groupID = 'EORG'` yes, if  `groupID` is a foreign key (it is so). I just rewrite HQL from a question. But I asked, can you use `inner join` in HQL without having a corresponding association in Hibernate 3?

Comment: @JoeTaras A bad practice, because of if you have an association,  you should have it in your mapping. Not simply plain keys, but objects. And `inner join` is a simply thing, using `left join` this way can be more complex.